# Screen X,Y co-ordinates translated to map Lon/Lat co-ordinates

Tags: java, c#

Good day.
I would like to convert a screen x,y pixel location (the location a user tapped/clicked) to a lon/lat location on a map.

The current screen location is in a bounding box, of which you have the top left most and bottom right most lon/lat values.

When the screen is not rotated it is quite simple to translate the x/y position to the lon,lat values:

- Let mapboudingbox[0,1] contain  top left most lat/lon
- mapboundingbox[2,3] contains bottom right most lat/lon

Then the degrees per pixel width = abs(lon2 - lon1)/ screenWidthInPixels

Then the degrees per pixel height = abs(lat2 - lat1)/ screenHeightInPixels

From this you can then get Lon/Lat as follow:

```
 float longitude = ((touchXInPixels) * degreesPerPixelWidth) + mapBoundingBox[1];
 float latitude = ((touchYPixels) * degreesPerPixelHeight) + mapBoundingBox[0];
```

This is easy enough. The problem that I have is calculating the Lat/Lon values when the screen is rotated, i.e:
[image: Rotated Screen]

From this, you can see that the screen has now been rotated by an angle Ө. -180 < Ө < 180

So let's assume the user clicks/taps on the screen FQKD at point Sx,Sy. How can I get the new lon/lat values where the user clicked, assuming that we have point Z and R in Lat/Lon, as well as the angle Ө, as well as the screen height and width in pixels?

Any and all help will be much appreciated!

Comment: Why is both c# and java?

Comment: How about showing the code you use to rotate, and position the map image? The finding of the click point is the inverse process.

Comment: Because I don't care the language. If I know the solution I can do it in either... The rotation of the map is handled by the mapping component in itself....
You would think there should be a simple function to get the tapped lon/lat ..... but NOOOOooo... :(

Comment: If you tell us the actual platform, it may have shortcuts. For example if you tell us this is Android, the solution is far simpler than the long hand, do it yourself, implementation.

Comment: The platform is Android ... The mapping component used is deCarta.

Comment: I would be surprised if there is not a simple deCarta API call that gives you what you want.

Comment: Hahaha.... be surprised then. I already asked and they said that what I want is not supported directly out of the box

Comment: How did you ask? Did you just say "I want to get the lat long of a press?"

Comment: Yes ... Kinda
"we would like to convert the screen coordinates received from the touch-event, to the geo-spatial coordinates on the map.

Currently we can do this without taking yaw and pitch into consideration, but need to take all d.o.f. into consideration."

Comment: They have a forum, have you tried on there as well as their support email?

Comment: Yes, I have. And the only response I get is that "this is not supported out of the box"

Answer (score 1):

I would just modify standard rotation and scale algorithm for 2D. Read a bit here: 
[2dTransformations](http://www.willamette.edu/~gorr/classes/GeneralGraphics/Transforms/transforms2d.htm).

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to achieve this is with matrices.

A 3x3 matrix can describe the rotation, translation & scale in 2D space.

Using this matrix you can project your map image on to the screen area. And using the inverse of the matrix, you can take a point in screen space to map space.

Pseudocode: (as you don't care what language)

Build your matrix:

```
var matrix = Matrix.newIdentity();
matrix.postAppendTranslate(tx, ty);
matrix.postAppendScale(zoom);
matrix.postAppendRotate(rot);
```

Render map image using that matrix.

To reverse a press:

```
var inverseMatrix = matrix.inverse();
var point = new float[]{touchPointX, touchPointY, 1};
var transformedPoint = inverseMatrix.multiply(point);
var mapX = transformedPoint[0];
var mapY = transformedPoint[1];
```

Comment: `tx`, `ty` is the translation of the map, so yeah probably Lon/Lat at point Z.

Comment: What Matrix class did you use? I'm trying to find this Matrix class you used. The closest one currently I could find wat the android.graphics.Matrix class, but it does not have the multiply function.

Comment: Well that's [Pseudocode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudocode), because you didn't want to specify the language/platform. If you use the `android.graphics.Matrix` use [`mapPoints`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Matrix.html#mapPoints(float[]))

Comment: There is an interesting method called [`setPolyToPoly`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Matrix.html#setPolyToPoly(float[], int, float[], int, int)) You might be able to use that to build the matrix from lat-longs and pixel coordinates that you know.

Comment: Not 100% sure how to use this. I'm scratching my head a bit